# SDL Multithreading: How to only block some data?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl

I have been following Lazy foo's tutorials on SDL multithreading and the way I understand it calling SDL_SemWait locks out all the data to the other thread. this would effectivly make the first thread useless because it has nothing to work with. I want to use multithreading to load files while a user is on the main menu but if all the data is locked how will this work?

Comment: your question is very abstract (no code given), so you'll only get comments or vague answers (like mine). If you have a specific problem, you should expand your question on that point, and show up a little bit of the code related to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

What a semaphore does is to *block* the calling thread until the semaphore value rises above zero (so it will not block if it is *already above zero*). What you want is to have your rendering thread keep rendering (the menu, or whatever it is supposed to do), while the other thread fills up some unrelated piece of data. If you want to keep the rendering thread busy, it must have at least the data used for rendering available. All the rest is up to you to decide how and when to load it up.